# How to split date time from string and after some action on date Time I want to concate date Time with this string dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, split, javascript-objects

how to split date from string using regex.

Job: JOB-72 has been rescheduled for: Wednesday, October 16, 2019 02:00 AM

I want to extract this date from string using regex Wednesday, October 9, 2019 8

Comment: could you give some examples?

Comment: Would you like to split `Job: JOB-72 has been rescheduled for: Wednesday, October 16, 2019 02:00 AM` at some point (e.g. at `:`) and add a new date, or what? :)

Comment: Expected result:
JOB-72 has been rescheduled for:  
Wednesday, October 16, 2019 02:00 AM

after spiting:

JOB-72 has been rescheduled for our customer:  
Wednesday, October 16, 2019 02:00 AM

Comment: @entiendoNull  my point is extract date Time and modify string and concate datetime with new string as in example.

Comment: @entiendoNull I want to extract this date from string using regex 
Wednesday, October 9, 2019 8

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you want.
But using `split` to modify parts of your string could be done this way...

```
const str = 'JOB-72 has been rescheduled for:Wednesday, October 16, 2019 02:00 AM';
const pieces = str.split(':'); // or whatever you want to split at
const description = pieces[0]; // contains: JOB-72 has been rescheduled for
const date = pieces[1]; // contains: October 16, 2019 02:00 AM

const newStr = `JOB-72 has been rescheduled for our customer: ${date}`;
```

Comment: 0: "Job"
1: " JOB-73 has been scheduled for"
2: " Wednesday, October 9, 2019 8"
3: "00 PM"

Comment: I want to extract this date from string using regex

Wednesday, October 9, 2019 8